# If both are UEFI, can I physically switch between a Win10 HDD and a Linux HDD as needed?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, uefi

I have a work laptop with Win10 that only has room for 1 HDD, though I have a spare drive. I'd like to *mostly* outright switch to Linux, but I don't want to commit 100% in case an issue arises for which I need to use Windows, or if I find some problem with a program my work uses that didn't exist in Windows.

So for that I'd like not to wipe it, or dual-boot. I'm hoping that, as they're both UEFI I could just freely physically swap the drives without issue, but I wanted to make sure this is indeed the case before I attempt it and possibly ruin something. Is this going to break anything? Or is there any other reason this would not be advisable?

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but there are a few things to consider.

1. Swapping the drives would likely take time and would get annoying over time.
2. There is a possibility of breaking a cable or something else, as most laptops are not designed to be taken apart often.

Here are some other possible methods:

If your laptop has a USB 3 port or something similar, you could get an adapter to plug the drive in to your laptop when you need it, although this too has its drawbacks. You would need to power the drive separately and you might have speed drawbacks. If you do this, you will also have to buy an enclosure for the drive to prevent damage to it.

Another possible method would be to buy an external drive. You can find them for quite cheap now, and they are designed to be run externally.

The last method I can think of doing this is installing it on a USB, like you would a drive. If you do this, you will have to use 2 USBs. Firstly, you will need one with the installation media, and one where you will be installing. I would recommend getting a cheap 64GB or 128GB thumb drive for this.